# Setting default path with custom variable in windows 10pro

Tags: windows

I have been trying to get windows to recognize shortcuts for developer tools. Things like adb for C:\Users\myusername\Andriod\platform-tools\adb.exe. I have tried using CMD and Powershell but they both don't add the PATH I tried the GUI and it doesn't show up.

I've tried `setx path "%PATH%;C:\path\to\C:\Users\myusername\Andriod\platform-tools\adb.exe"` in powershell and cmd then restarted powershell or cmd
input the variable adb but it pulls a command not recognized error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

- Adding the path "C:\Users\myusername\Andriod\platform-tools" to your system/user PATH variable? You can do this by start-> environment variable -> environment variable and under system or user, edit the PATH variable and add the above link. Once you do this, restart CMD for it to work.
- Add the executable in one of the already existing locations that are in the PATH variable. (Although this is one method, I would not suggest this). Again, if the executable has any dependencies, it must be in a place where the exe itself can access.

Comment: ```'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file``` I want to use adb as a shortcut to "C:\Users\myusername\Andriod\platform-tools\adb.exe" in the cmd or powershell. I have added it to Path environment variables and PATH.

Comment: I just tried it myself. 
- I downloaded ADB from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip.
- Extracted it to a folder (Make sure it is a local path Ex - Make sure it is not in onedrive etc). 
- Added the path of the extracted folder to the System PATH variable. 
- Restarted CMD and typed adb 
It just worked. Where are you putting your adb.exe ?

Comment: Its moved it to documents\platform-tools\adb.exe but it only pulls up when I use the entire directory C:User\Documents\Platform-Tools\adb.exe in the cmd. Is there a way to link the variable adb to C:User\Documents\Platform-Tools\adb.exe? So that when I type adb it short_cuts in the command line to the executable? This is so much easier on a Mac.

Comment: If you are pasting the correct path in the system PATH variable and saved and restarted CMD, it should work. If it is not working, check your path. Ex - Copy your path, and open cmd from start -> CMD. Do a CD <copied path> and see if it works. In your above example, you should have 'C:\User\Documents\Platform-Tools' copied to your system PATH. And if you have one-drive working, this documents will be under onedrive.